# (python) Let a string be recognised as a already defined variable

Tags: python, string, variables

```
x= 1

a_1_add = "message 1"
a_2_add = "message 2"

while x<3:
   y = "a_" + x + "_add"
   print(y)
   x += 1
```

How do I get python to get make it print "message 1', "message 2" instead of "a_1_add"?
I want to **specifically make the string in y to be recognised as a variable**. How to I do that?

I want to have a code that automatically change from the variable "a_1_add" to "a_2_add" and so on but don't want to manually write it out since the difference is only the number in the middle.

Edit: I know of "for loop" (a thank you to those that suggested it) but for my code (not so simple as the example I wrote out) I really need to use the while loop.

Thanks in advance. I am a beginner in python. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: "specifically make the string in y to be recognised as a variable." *don't do that*. Strings are not variables. Variable names shouldn't contain data. Don't try to use variables dynamically from strings. Use a *container* like a list or a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're beginner, I would assume, you should look toward something like this instead:

```
a_1_add = "message 1"
a_2_add = "message 2"

container = [a_1_add, a_2_add]

for element in container:
    print(element)
```

Note, you can still access the contents of both variables `a_1_add` and `a_2_add`, change them, add more variables to the `container` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the `for` loop to loop through all the variables.

```
var1 = “message 1”
var2 = “message 2”
var3 = “message 3”

for i in [var1, var2, var3]:
    print(i)
```

## Edit:

Yes, as @juanpa.arrivillage suggested , `string` `list` `dictionary` etc. are all *data types* (built in) in Python. *Variables* are user-defined, just a name representing the value assigned to it.

I think I get what you mean: like create variables using `whilè loop`? If so, I m afraid that it is not possible. Maybe you can use an array to contain those all values instead ? and access them using `index` or `slicing`.

```
x = 1
all_val = []  # this is a list here

while x < 3:
    all_val.append(f"a_{x}_add")
    x += 1

print(all_val[0])
print(all_val[1])
print(all_val[1:])
```

Hope it can answer you question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I = 1
    tuto1 = input("type I\n")
    #how to do this
    if(tuto1 == 1):
```

whatever_my_name_is@penguin:~$random_stuff.py
type I
I

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).